# Why can't CircleCi find my tests?

Tags: testing, circleci

Please see repo structure below. I want to run the tests in root/app2/tests/. I am using py.test.

After CircleCi couldn't infer test directory automatically I added a circle.yml file to the root directory but still the tests are not found. Any help greatly appreciated.

circle.yml file content:

```
general:
  build_dir: app2/tests
```

Repository structure:

```
root
├── circle.yml
├── app1
│   ├── xxx
│   ├── yyy
│  
└── app2
    ├── src
    ├── tests
        |-- test_module_1.py
        |-- test_module_2.py
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok with help from CircleCI I figured out how to use py.test with CircleCI:

In the `circle.yml` file add:

```
test:
    override:
        - py.test <optional path to subdir with tests>

dependencies:
    pre:
       -  pip install pytest
```

If your code relies on several packages in addition to py.test, you can create a requirements.txt file:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

place the requirements.txt file in the same directory as the circle.yml file (or in the build_dir if you have specified that in your circle.yml file) and add to circle.yml:

```
dependencies:
      pre:
         -  pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: I tried this but I get "...ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. ..." when it tries to install pytest

Answer (score 0):

It’s generally enough to set the `build_dir` to just the application directory, we’ll take care of finding the tests subdirectory ourselves.

Could you please try replacing your current command in the `circle.yml` with this?

```
general:
  build_dir: app2
```